# Can somebody post links for Log4j tutorial

Tags: java, log4j

Whenever i search in the internet for log4j tutorial, i got the sample property filr or configuration file, but did not get the tutorial on how to configure property file and xml file...

The official documentation of apache for log4j is not clear,

Can somebody post the link for log4j tutorials...?

If there is any books available online, it would be helpful to download and study..

Comment: I thought the log4j docs were quite good.  Any specific things you're struggling with?

Comment: @leonm - What do I say when someone asks me "What EXACTLY is the prupose of log4j ?". Is this a good answer - Logging all the errors generated by methods of a class ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This [tutorial from Lalinuna](http://www.laliluna.de/articles/log4j-tutorial.html) is great. There is also pdf and source code with snippets of code. Go for it :)

Answer (score 3):

[Here's one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/).  I've found another link for you.

Answer (score 3):

The [Log4j manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) covers every aspect, from API to configuration. It's quite short, but very complete.

Answer (score 0):

[DZone's tutorial*](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/log4j/log4j-tutorial/log4j-tutorial.html)

*(this chars is just to pass the answers's body validator!!!!! ;))

Comment: Link is broken. Don't know if it supposed to point to the same one as @duffymo

Comment: @Irene In case, you are still looking for links, here are two; http://www.journaldev.com/7128/apache-log4j-2-tutorial-configuration-levels-appenders-lookup-layouts-and-filters-example and https://www.laliluna.de/download/log4j-tutorial-en.pdf